# confused with mobile friendly websites or related

Tags: html, css

I read somewhere that once you log in here (http://skweezer.com/) and put the website url, we can get the way the site will appear on mobile browsers. I tried getting this url (http://sachindra149.wordpress.com/) and was baffled to see he way it looked.

1) Can anyone please let me know why is that so ??

2) Why such a major difference???

3) And also what needs to be done ...

keeping one thing in mind that I dont have the control over the web codes for the page as it is a blog....
Hope I am clear enough !!!!!!!!

Comment: Note that no one is going to register to skweezer.com just to see how your site looks in it, so please attach a screen capture or explain your problem otherwise.

Comment: i too didnt get logged in there .. plz just get there and type the url in the text box ... tahts it ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it just dumps pages to text. That isn't a realistic view of what mobile browsers do these days. Unless you are explicitly developing websites for low end and old mobile devices, don't worry about it.

If you are developing websites for such devices, then:

- Don't use generic blog hosting which doesn't give you lots of control
- Avoid tabular data
- Avoid chrome (large navigation, anything that isn't the primary content)
- Keep content short and to the point
- Test of real mobile devices instead of third party emulators

Comment: .. so do u mean this skweezer.com might not be correct in that ??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not as bad as it looks. Mobile device have only very limited resources but they are much better today.

What you see on [skweezer.com](http://skweezer.com/) is just the raw text without CSS styling, tables and other complicated HTML. This way, the site loads much (!) faster and you only transfer a fraction of the data. Your original site needs 320KB, the skweezer version needs 50KB - less than 1/6th. Mobile browsing got much faster and cheaper but it's still many times slower and more expensive than on the desktop.

As for what you can do about it: Not much. You could select a design which is optimized for mobile devices but to know how good it looks, you would need all mobile devices that access your site. I suggest to rely on the experience of the designers at Wordpress. Your site does look much better on most mobile devices.

Comment: not quite getting to understand.. relying on wordpress' designers ?? bt the site is a blog in wordpress only.... what i feel is that i shud nt rely on skweezer and shud get to check on the mobile only  ??? is that it???

Comment: Yes, skweezer isn't an iPad, iPhone, or whatever you use. You can't rely on it to tell you what it looks for other people. On top of that, the people at Wordpress are trying hard to make your blog look good anywhere, so you shouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer checking them on real devices.

Chrome extension like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/objclahbaimlfnbjdeobicmmlnbhamkg?hl=en) will help you vew your website on different screen sizes if there is a limit on devices.